# Confusion about random variables and what they mean

Tags: probability, random-variable

I am not a statistician, and just try to understand a concept. According to Wikipedia,

> A random variable is defined as a function that maps outcomes to
>   numerical quantities (labels), typically real numbers. In this sense,
>   it is a procedure for assigning a numerical quantity to each physical
>   outcome, and, contrary to its name, this procedure itself is neither
>   random nor variable. What is random is the unstable physics that
>   describes how the coin lands, and the uncertainty of which outcome
>   will actually be observed.

My understanding is,

> The *domain of a random variable is the set of possible
>   outcomes*, and *the range of a random variable is whatever we
>   set it to be*. For instance, if $\mathcal{X}$ was a random variable
>   for the coin tossing random process, both of the followings would
>   still be proper to define: $$\mathcal{X}:
> > \{\text{head,tail}\}\rightarrow \{0,1\}\ \ \ \text{OR} \ \ \
> > \mathcal{X}: \{\text{head,tail}\}\rightarrow \{102,321312\}.$$ Random
>   variables are the starting block for doing computations. That's all
>   they do!

Is this correct?

Now, I am trying to understand the following statement from [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.05986.pdf) paper:

> Suppose we are given a positive function $f : \{1 ... m\} \rightarrow
> > R^+$, which describes the unnormalized mass of a discrete random
>   variable $I$,
>
> $P(I\in B) = \sum_{i\in B}\frac{f(i)}{\sum_j^m f(j)}, \text{ where }
> > B\subset\{1...m\}$

My immediate reaction when I hear the term `function` is to assume an infinite vector. In this case the $f$ vector length is bounded by $m$, and it encodes in each cell of the vector a positive real number. This can be considered as an unnormalized probability vector of a discrete random variable $I$, whose domain is $\{1 ... m\}$, and board is $R^+$. So far, this is fine.

Now, what I don't understand is the notation in the $P(I\in B)$. What does it mean? How can a function $I$ be a member of set of integers from $\{1 ... m\}$? From what I understand $I$ is not a single value, but is a function. It seems the designed interpretation is that we assume a particular input of $I$, which means $P(I\in B)$ implicitly means $P(I(i\in{B}))$, which then can be rewritten as $\sum_{i\in B}P(I(i))$. Now, since we assumed $f$ to be the unnormalized probability vector representing $I$, we can use it to compute the probability of each of the $i$ assignments by just normalizing it $$\sum_{i\in B}P(I(i))=\sum_{i\in B}\frac{f(i)}{\sum_{j\in B}f(j)}.$$

So, subject to some refinements, I can understand the notation $P(I\in B)$, but I am not sure if what I described is accurate.

Comment: Your thinking appears good, but the notation is a little off.  Expressions like "$\Pr(I\in B)$" are shorthand for the probabilities of events $$``I\in B" = \{\omega\in \Omega\mid I(\omega)\in B\}.$$The function $f$ thereby can be *defined* as $$f(i)=\Pr(I\in\{i\})=\Pr(\{\omega\in\Omega\mid I(\omega)=i\}).$$ The advantage of this shorthand is that it requires no explicit mention of the underlying probability space $\Omega.$

Answer (score 3):

There's an (unmentioned) space $\Omega$, which is, as you say, ''the set of possible outcomes'' of a random experiment. The random variable $I$ is a function from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb R$. The notation
$$ I \in B$$
is short for
$$ \{ \omega \in \Omega : I(\omega) \in B \}. $$
Thus, $P(I \in B)$ is the probability of this event.

In this case $I$ can take only values in $\{1, \dots, m\}$, or if you prefer, $I(\Omega) \subseteq \{1, \dots, m\}$. You have
$$\begin{aligned} P(I \in B) &= P( I(\omega) = 1 \text{ or } \dots \text{ or }  I(\omega) = m ) \\
&= P( I(\omega) = 1 ) + \cdots +  P( I(\omega) = m ).
\end{aligned}$$

The function $f$ is such that 
$$ P( I(\omega) = i ) \propto f(i), $$
which leads to the statement you mentioned.

Comment: It is still not clear. What does it mean to say $I(\omega) \in B$, when $I$ is a function from generating real-valued numbers in $\mathbb R$, and $B$ is just a set of integers?

Comment: Well, $\mathbb N \subset \mathbb R$. The fact that a function takes its values in $\mathbb R$ does not prevent it to take integer values. This particular function $I : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb R$ happens to take only integer values.

Comment: This other question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141416/example-of-sample-x-1-x-2-ldots-x-n is not directly related to your question, but it may help you to understand better the idea of random variables.